# Problem writing a colored rectangle in OpenCV

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

I wrote a class called PatternGenerator. It is supposed to write an image from a given color pattern (or chart). Something like this:

[image]

After getting the color pattern in CieLAB as a *numpy.ndarray* with shape *(1, x, 3)* [where x would be the amount of colors (3 channels each)], I converted to RGB by doing *cv2.cvtColor(pattern, cv2.COLOR_LAB2RGB)*. Of course I got numbers between [0, 1], so I multiplied by 255.

Then, I tried to write the image by doing the following:

```
image = np.zeros((self.color_size * self.cols, self.color_size * self.rows, 3))

for x in pattern[0]:
     color = x.astype(int).tolist()
     for i in range(self.cols):
         for j in range(self.rows):
             cv.rectangle(image, (i * self.color_size, j * self.color_size),
                          (i * self.color_size + self.color_size, j * self.color_size + self.color_size),
                          color, thickness = cv2.FILLED)

cv2.imwrite('result.png', image)
```

*self.color_size*: would be the size in pixels of the color square.

Now comes the problem. The thing is, if instead of *color*, I put, let's say something like (i ** 2, j ** 2, i+j), it works totally fine (these colors don't have any sense, it was just for testing). BUT, if I input the variable *color*, which stands for the LAB2RGB conversion, followed by a cast to int (I also tried np.uint8, np.int, np.uint16), and then to *Python's list* (I did all this because the errors asked me to), it outputs a gray image. No rectangle of any type, even though when printing the numbers (their channels), the colors were all completely different.

On the other hand, I did try something different. My pure numpy approach was something like:

```
def _concatenate_colors(self, colors: list) -> np.ndarray:
    image = []
    for x in colors[0]:
        color = np.full((self.color_size, self.color_size, 3), x)
        image.append(color)
```

Now, if I convert to numpy.ndarray, I get a *(n_colors, self.color_size, self.color_size, 3)*. And I got stuck here. Basically I don't know how to reshape this into a (self.color_size * self.cols, self.color_size * self.rows, 3) while mantaining each square intact.

**edit: I tried BGR conversion as well. It should have at least interpreted other colors. But I got a gray image.**

Any other method, function already available that I don't know of...is welcome.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: "I converted to RGB" -- well, that's a problem, since `imwrite` expects BGR.

Comment: I tried BGR as well. It should have at least interpreted other colors. But I got a gray image.

Comment: Yeah, that's interesting. What are the exact values of the colors, before and after the conversion? What's the relationship befween `n_colors` and `self.cols`/`self.rows`?

Comment: Anyway, since you tag this with OpenCV -- easy approach is to create an array where each "tile" is just a single pixel. i.e. in the example case you'd have shape (6,6,3). Then, use `cv2.resize` with `INTER_AREA` to scale the tiles up to the desired size.

Comment: Yeap, I solved it that way, but it's definitely not the cleanest approach as it isn't scalable to other patterns.

Comment: Sure, but your example showed a regular rectangular grid, so that's what I went for. For that particular problem, this is IMHO quite concise and efficient performance wise. What other patterns did you have in mind?

Comment: I might have to implement a grid of circles later on :/